# rewrite www.mysite.com requests to www-staging.mysite.com with .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I have a staging and production Apache server. To access staging I just go to `www-staging.mysite.com/a/sub/directory`. To access production, just remove the `-staging` in the `www`.

Currently, all the links on my staging try and reach out to the production versions. I want to say in my .htaccess file,

> "if on www-staging, modify all mysite.com requests to be
>   www-staging.mysite.com"

The .htaccess file is like a foreign language to me, so I'm really struggling figuring out how to do this. Here's my current code, which appears to have zero affect on my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www-staging.mysite.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include `Options +FollowSymLinks` meaning your .htaccess should look something like below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www-staging.mysite.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is to *not* use absolute links on your site, only relative links. (i.e. instead of having your pages with hardcoded URLs like `http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar` you'd have URLs like `/foo/bar`.

You are asking to rewrite the *content* which apache doesn't do.

However if I'm mistaken and you do use relative links - there's one thing you can do: configure two VHosts for staging and production. If you want to eliminate duplication use Include statement. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www
  Include conf.d/www.mysite.com.common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www-staging.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www-staging
  Include conf.d/www.mysite.com.common
</VirtualHost>
```

where `/etc/httpd/conf.d/www.mysite.com.common` defines some common settings for both sites.